# AngularJS forms and html5 validation messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

All the examples I found relating HTML5 and AngularJS forms are only showing that the user should use `novalidate` on their form to skip the browser validation.

What I'm trying to do is, somehow, be able to display HTML5 errors/error messages on AngularJS forms. I couldn't find anything related to `forms` neither to `ng-messages`. I'm looking at `ng-messages` because I want to use the messages in personalized template.

So far I found that the error message is related to the form element (input, textarea, etc) and can be accessed via `element` variable using directives. Like:

```
function link(scope, element) {
  element.on('blur', function() {
    var message = element[0].validationMessage !== "" ? element[0].validationMessage : undefined;

    if (message) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I want to do:
[image: Input validated using HTML5 and showing message]

Does somebody know a good how can I get the messages?

Thanks

**Edited:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':cmFormModel.$invalid && !cmFormModel.$pristine}">
  <input
    type="email"
    name="myEmail"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="myModel"
    placeholder="E-mail"
    uib-tooltip="{{tooltipMessage}}"
    tooltip-placement="{{tooltipPlacement}}"
    tooltip-trigger="none"
    tooltip-is-open="isTooltipOpen"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: Thanks @tuckerjt07 . Not sure how this would help but this close to the input I printed:

`<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':cmFormModel.$invalid && !cmFormModel.$pristine}">
  <input
    type="email"
    name="myEmail"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="myModel"
    placeholder="E-mail"
    uib-tooltip="{{tooltipMessage}}"
    tooltip-placement="{{tooltipPlacement}}"
    tooltip-trigger="none"
    tooltip-is-open="isTooltipOpen"/>
</div>`

I'm using angular-ui bootstrap for the tooltip and simple html to style it.

Comment: Can you put that into formatted code? Also, what attributes are you adding to the form tag?

Comment: @tuckerjt07 not adding any special tag to the form. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: If you are wanting to use your own validations and messages you need the novalidate attribute

Comment: @tuckerjt07 now you got to the point. I want use HTML5 validations as my validations...